# $.post jquery function return not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have HTML code like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button" onclick="addtocart();">Tambah Item</button>
```

And I want to execute this jQuery function:

```
function addtocart() {
    var url = '<?php echo BASE_URL."modul/penjualan_barang/content/cart.php"?>'
    $.post(url+'?act=addcart',{barcode:$(".combo-value").val()},function(result){
        alert(result);

        if (result.success){
            $.messager.alert('Benar','Terdapat kesalahan ketika proses menginput, coba refresh halaman anda','error');  
        } else {
            $.messager.alert('Kesalahan','Terdapat kesalahan ketika proses menginput, coba refresh halaman anda','error');  
        }
    },'json');      

}
```

But I can't get any result for that function, so I don't know if it's working or not.

Any suggestion please???

Comment: Are you checking your browser's console and seeing any Javascript errors or anything?

Comment: i'm not got any error on console..

Comment: Have you tried adding an alert `before` the `$.post` to make sure that the function is firing at least?

Comment: You might want to turn this into an `$.ajax` call instead of `$.post` so that you can use the `error` option and see what's happening. I'm guessing you're getting a 404 or 500 HTTP error

Comment: @Abhilash i already try to add alert before $.post and it works, but it doesnt when i write the alert inside $.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback only executes when the POST request returns HTTP 200 (success). You must be getting an error code response from the server.

The Chrome plugin "REST Console can help debug the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting a result, it's most likely that you're either getting an error back from the server, the post request isn't being sent (same origin issues), or you're not getting back a response from the server at all.

In order to quickly identify the issue, I recommend firing up [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and seeing what the request and response is for your Post request.

Fiddler2 is an HTTP Debugging utility written by [Eric Lawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126229/ericlaw) and one of it's features is a Inspector that shows the request and it's matching response. If your server is returning an HTTP error, you should see it there.

Chrome Developer Tools can help as well, but I recommend installing and learning how to use Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I think extra close braces ("}") is present in your code (function addtocart).Please check once.